# Is working memory somewhat task specific?

Tags: working-memory

Working memory (WM) is often associated with intelligence and can supposedly be measured and trained by games like [dual n-back](http://brainscale.net/dual-n-back). My question is if WM is task specific or has at least a task specific component. Or rather, my *intuition* is that it is: Me training dual-n back 20 minutes are day will improve my ability to play dual n-back far more than it will improve my ability to juggle different ways of asking this question in my head while writing it.

I think this is testable, so did anyone test if WM is task dependent and what did they find?

**Edit to add:**
[This question with answers on the cross-discipline benefits](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/207/does-learning-one-discipline-improve-performance-in-another-discipline) was marked as a possible duplicate. My question is not addressed: [The accepted answer](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/302/3900) to the question explores different ways cognitive abilities might 'transfer' from one discipline to another. One important aspect here is specific sub skills - psychologists may have a strong math background that may be useful when they learn. Another important aspect is the use of metaphors.
The supposed duplicate is relevant when discussing skill transfer between tasks. WM training is often hyped as general intelligence training. There are more straightforward ways of addressing this hype, my (maybe a bit roundabout) way is questioning wether WM trained on one task is as useful for another task.

Comment: There are 2 questions answered by [@RobinKramer](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/users/11318/robin-kramer) which may help. http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/13118/cognitive-models-of-learning-working-memory-usage is one, and http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/14068/7604 goes a little bit more into the answer

Comment: Thanks for the reference @Chris, perhaps these question about transfer may also be of interest to you Mart: https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/207/does-learning-one-discipline-improve-performance-in-another-discipline and http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/15779/cognitive-models-for-transfer-of-skills

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does learning one discipline improve performance in another discipline?](http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/207/does-learning-one-discipline-improve-performance-in-another-discipline)

Comment: This answer could indicate that my intuition is wrong http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/15974/3900 but does IMO not directly answer the question.

Comment: I know there have been a lot of suggestions of possible duplicates ... but I really think this one addresses the actual question of whether training (such as dual n-back) improves working memory in general: [Is consistent dual n-back training likely to improve the performance of analysis (mathematics) students?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/4145/7001)